# input external parameters java fx

Tags: input, console, javafx

I need to run a program from the command line. There should be two inputs. username and password.

My problem is that I cannot find a clean easy way to do it. Either my syntax in the CMD console is bad or my code...

My code looks like this:

> ```
>     stage.setScene(scene);
>     stage.setTitle("Bmi Calculator");
>     stage.setResizable(false);
>
>     final Parameters params = getParameters();
>     final List<String> parameters = params.getRaw();
>     BMI.username = parameters.get(0);
>     BMI.password = parameters.get(1);
>
>     stage.show();
> ```

The problem is catching the input. I'm trying to set the variables from the main class to the two public static variables in my contoller class.

My CMD input would look like this: 
Start BmiCalculator.jar e:\Desktop\BmiCalculator.jar username password

// Alex

Comment: What is the problem? Are your static fields set to `null` after this code executes?

Comment: I don't seem to get it working. The syntax might be wrong?

Comment: No they stay the same =)

Comment: What do you mean, "they stay the same"?

Comment: Never mind! the problem was I used .getRaw(); i changed it to getunnamed() and walla it worked. I allso moved some methods to start abit later, they started without the input which coused the errors. =)

Comment: Ah. I was going to suggest you use that method but I needed to be sure of your problem.